# I am new to angular.js , please help me resolve the below error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

my code for angular is below  for which i am getting the error please have a look and suggest me on the same.
please help to resolve the error as i am stuck there.

```js
<html ng-app>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="padding:50px ">
<div  ng-app="myApp"  ng-controller="AlbumListController">
<p><input type="text" placeholder ="Type to search..." ng-model="searchFor" size ="30"/> </p>
<p>
there are number of {{albums.length}} albums for me
</p>
<br>
<br>
 <div class=" album panel panel-primary" ng-repeat="album in albums | filter:{title:searchFor} | orderBy: 'date'" >
   <div class="panel-heading">
     <div class= "date"> {{album.date}}</div>
    {{album.title}} 
    </div >
   <div class="discrption">
    {{album.discrption}}
   </div>
 </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

 var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
  app.controller('AlbumListController', function($scope){
   $scope.albums = [ {name: 'Goa',title: 'GoaFun',date: '21/10/2014',discrption: 'My first Goa Fun'},
  {name: 'MahaBlaeshwer',title: 'MahaBlaeshwerFun',date: '21/10/2013',discrption: 'My first MahaBlaeshwer Fun'},
 {name: 'Iceland',title: 'IceLandFun',date: '21/10/2016',discrption: 'My first Iceland Fun'},
 {name: 'Austrailia',title: 'AustrailiaFun',date: '21/10/2015',discrption: 'My first Austrailia Fun'} ] ;
 })
 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the error i am getting is below

> Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/ng/areq?p0=AlbumListController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
>           at Error (native)

Comment: try removing ng-app from html tag

Comment: Code seems working for me http://plnkr.co/edit/5EBoSWjebUUymsbckamr?p=preview you need to remove ng-app from html tag

Answer (score 1):

You have an unnecessary `ng-app` in the html tag.  Remove it as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
...
</html>
```

Check out the following fiddle, which doesn't include the html tag because it's already provided, and it works:

https://jsfiddle.net/gymkyw7g/

Also, check out the Angular documentation for ngApp, specifically this line:

> AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

By specifying ng-app in your html tag, as well as in a nested div, it was violating this constraint.

Comment: Thanks all for help the issue is fixed now!!